# Boot menu isn't being displayed

Tags: windows-7, windows

I formatted the whole  hard drive , and now I can't even get to boot menu . It asks me to press f8  after which it shows       go-!  >Boot menu ! Whatever key I hit doesn't get me to boot menu ! Please help!

Comment: If you wiped the HD entirely then it has nothing to boot to off the HD. Boot to disk or USB to an OS or installation that will allow you to install an OS onto the HD so you can then boot to it if that's what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Formatting will wipe the contents of a drive so that it can no longer be used. That includes the OS and the boot loader/manager. I'm not sure why you're still seeing Windows boot manager, but I'm guessing it may be because the format didn't complete fully. Either way, it's unclear from your question what you're trying to do here. Did you accidentally format the drive when you didn't mean to? Is it the only drive in your system?

Answer (score 0):

Two things, first, Windows' bootloader hasn't operated entirely from the MBR since Windows ME. Every version of Windows since 2000 (and possibly the NT variants before that) kept a sizable portion of the bootloader on the filesystem with Windows. Destroy the filesystem (by formatting it) and you destroy the boot loader.... hence no boot menu.

Further more, starting with Windows Vista, Windows has supported a newer boot method called EFI. EFI has an entire partition separate from the Windows filesystem dedicated to holding the boot loader for Windows (and any other EFI capable operating systems you have installed). In the case of EFI the MBR isn't used at all and, in fact, doesn't exist (it's technically still there... but it's *really* not supposed to be used by anything). Once again, destroy this EFI boot partition and you destroy the Windows bootloader.

If you at least left the factory-created recovery partition intact then you should be able to launch into the recovery environment and perform a factory restore using that... though from what you have said it doesn't sound like you did. If you really really deleted and formatted the whole drive (including all partitions) then you will need to contact your computer's manufacturer and acquire factory restore disks so you can recreate the recovery partition and then factory restore Windows from there. Or you can plop down ~$150 for a new copy of Windows 10... which your computer may not run very well since you were using Windows 7 before. Or borrow a Windows 7 install disk from a friend and hope it will accept your volume license (the license sticker on your case somewhere). I'm sorry, there are just no good options.